Backgrounds no me da el color de fondo si la celda es un valor desplegable con su color asignado
En Google Apps Script, la función getBackgrounds() no me facilita el color de fondo de las celdas que tienen un color asignado en un desplegable.¿Cómo puedo obtener el color de fondo de dichas celdas?
Adjunto imagen con el test de lo que digo:


Lo que te falta allí este verificar con una iteracion sobre la celda:
Aqui el Codigo:
unction myFunction() {
  let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  let sSource = ss.getSheetByName('Full 1');
  let rang = sSource.getDataRange();
  let aData = rang.getValues();
  let aBackg = rang.getBackgrounds();
  
  // Aquí es donde te digo que iteras sobre cada celda
  for (let i = 0; i < aData.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < aData[i].length; j++) {
      let valor = aData[i][j];
      let colorFondo = aBackg[i][j];
      
      // y aqui verificar si la celda tiene un color de fondo
      if (colorFondo !== "") {
        Logger.log("Celda [" + (i+1) + "," + (j+1) + "] tiene el color: " + colorFondo + " y el valor: " + valor);
      }
    }
  }
}


Resumen
Aquí hay un problema de expectativas y de concepto.
Sobre las expectativas
No todo los que se puede hacer usando la interfaz de la hoja de cálculo de Google se puede hacer on Google Apps Script o incluso ni con la API.
Sobre conceptos
El desplegable es una forma de mostrar la validación de datos. Los colores de la validación de datos se sobreponen sobre el color de la celda, en otras palabras, al ojo se muestra un color diferente al color de fondo de la celda, sin embargo dicha propiedad no cambia.
Recomendación
Consulta la documentación, específicamente la que se refiere a la validación de datos.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-validation

Relacionado

Solicitud de característica nueva en el "Issue Tracker" oficial de Google Apps Script: "chip" style for drop-down menu in data validation from apps script

